# How to make ant target exclusive to each other?

Tags: ant

In ANT, it is easy to set target dependency by using the attribute target.depends.

But how can I setup some target that they are exclusive to each other. So it will check the target combination before execute them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make each of them define a common property, and be executed only if this property is not set yet :

```
<target name="a" unless="aOrBAlreadyRun">
    <property name="aOrBAlreadyRun" value="true"/>
    ...
</target>

<target name="b" unless="aOrBAlreadyRun">
    <property name="aOrBAlreadyRun" value="true"/>
    ...
</target>
```

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html for explanations.

**EDIT :**

If you want the build to fail when both targets are executed, then fail if the property is already set :

```
<target name="a">
    <fail if="aOrBAlreadyRun" 
          message="You can't have a and b executed in the same build"/>
    <property name="aOrBAlreadyRun" value="true"/>
    ...
</target>

<target name="b">
    <fail if="aOrBAlreadyRun" 
          message="You can't have a and b executed in the same build"/>
    <property name="aOrBAlreadyRun" value="true"/>
    ...
</target>
```

Comment: It check and skip after either one executed, without warning nor error message.

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like ant to exit with an error if both targets are executed?

Comment: Cool. It is possible to warn it before? not stop it after?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do exclusive that is very simple.

Just don't write them into same build.xml file but make a copy of it and modify two version accordingly.